# Send each keys slower because textbox cannot handle sending keys fast

Tags: selenium

Send keys on textbox much slower, the problem is on this textbox if you send too fast, it kinda does not get inputted because there is a suggestion that drops down, if you send keys without any pause, it does not send it properly.

Sample is sometimes it inputes like sampl supp, sampledepartment.
Something like that.

You also need to press enter because it is a new type of department or category, because if you do not select something in the dropdown you can input a new one but just pressing enter.

I tried putting implicit wait on each element and tried clicking, clearing it then inputting text

```
//Input department
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement department = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='txtdepartment txtenter_event']"));
department.click();
department.clear();
department.sendKeys("sample department", Keys.ENTER);
System.out.println("Successful in inputting department");

//Input category
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement category = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='txtcategory txtenter_event']"));
category.click();
category.clear();
category.sendKeys("sample category", Keys.ENTER);
System.out.println("Successful in inputting category");

//Input supplier
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement supplier = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='txtsupplier txtenter_event']"));
supplier.click();
supplier.clear();
supplier.sendKeys("sample supplier", Keys.ENTER);
System.out.println("Successful in inputting supplier");
```

I expect to input the keys without any error.

Comment: What error do you see and at which line?

Comment: sorry about that , there is no error but it sends wrong input on the send keys part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use JavaScript to sendKeys:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement department = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='txtdepartment txtenter_event']"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'sample department');", department);
```

You can use like this:

> js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'arguments[1]');", element, inputValue);

Answer (score 0):

I typically just use a macro program like AppRobotic Personal to send one letter a time, with a delay in between. Something like the code below should work for you:

```
import win32com.client
x = win32com.client.Dispatch("AppRobotic.API")
from selenium import webdriver
x.MoveCursor(100,100)
x.MouseLeftClick
x.Type("{BACKSPACE}")
# wait 200 milliseconds
x.Wait(200)
#Type 'the' while waiting between each letter
x.Type("t")
x.Wait(200)
x.Type("h")
x.Wait(200)
x.Type("e")
x.Wait(200)
x.Type("{ENTER}")
```